# HTML5 Video autoplay is not working in incognito mode chrome

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, html5-video

The video is set as a background for HTML div:

```
 <video preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted="muted">
          <source src="assets/videos/section-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="assets/videos/section-video.webm" type="video/webm">
          <source src="assets/videos/section-video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

The video is saved in assets folder (Angular app) the video is fully working on firefox and chrome but not in chrome incognito mode.

Comment: Any console errors ?

Comment: No! the console is empty.

Comment: What's the size of your video ?

Comment: 4.69 MB. When I open it from the URL directly ex: http://localhost:4200/assets/videos/section-video.mp4 it will work perfect but not inside our HTML code.

Comment: Well then I don't know sorry ... If you can provide a [mcve] to play with ?

Comment: What exactly "isn't working" when you try to use incognito mode? Is the video not shown at all?

Comment: I tried another video URL from other source it worked perfect! but why my video not working on on chrome incognito mode ?!

Comment: @MikeS. the video is shown but the autoplay not working.

Comment: I see. Chrome has an autoplay policy that usually allows muted autoplay, however I'm not sure if the same applies to incoginto (where it might get blocked completely).